# How do you interpret the message I received from the chair of search committee?

Tags: faculty-application, tenure-track, interview

I recently attended a campus interview for a tenure-track faculty position. I think it did not go too bad overall. As soon as I came back I sent thank-you notes to which I got generally positive responses, even two said that they would like to collaborate with me in the future. Earlier this week I sent an enquiry email asking if there was any update and received an email from the chair of the search committee moments later saying that I should "definitely" watch my phone in the next two weeks for a call from the Dean, also highlighting that if I get an offer from another university I should let them know asap so that they can "speed-wrap" things faster on their end. I tend to interpret this as if I got the job, but I do not want to get carried away. Any idea would be much appreciated. I find it very hard to live my life with this uncertainty!

Comment: This question is not a good fit as it depends on individual factors. Noone except the people involved in hiring at that university know exactly what is going on. Just wait.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/189399/40589

Comment: Such decisions are usually done by more than one person (e.g., a committee), and what is not uncommon is that there are meetings scheduled for making the final decision. This means nothing is fixed until the meeting. You getting an offer from elsewhere may be a reason for them to reschedule the meeting (to earlier) or make the decision without a meeting earlier, so you can get a decision earlier. But this is extra work, so it is not unreasonable to only do that if you have an offer from elsewhere. Of course, I can't know if all of this is reason in *your* case, but it's plausible.

Answer (score 6):

The signs are good, but until such time as you have the actual offer in hand, you won't know and there is nothing you can do about it: Before it is legally decided that you should get the job, nobody is going to tell you something definitive. As a consequence, the only thing you can do is pour yourself a glass of good wine and stay positive.

Comment: It ain't over till the fat lady sings. Or better make that: it ain't over till the enormous person sings.